# Why does $ \int_0^1 x^z (1-x)^z dx$ become $\int_{-1}^1 \left(\frac{1+s}{2}\right)^z \left(\frac{1-s}{2}\right)^z \frac{1}{2}ds$?

Tags: integration, definite-integrals

In P Nahin's *Inside Interesting Integrals* it is shown that on page 129:
$$B(z+1,z+1) = \int_0^1 x^z (1-x)^z dx$$
Then he makes a change of variable such that $x=\frac{1+s}{2}$ to get 
$$\int_{-1}^1 \left(\frac{1+s}{2}\right)^z \left(\frac{1-s}{2}\right)^z \frac{1}{2}ds$$
Now though it is a simple question:

I cannot see why the limits become $-1$ and $1$?

the upper limit would be 1 from $1=\frac{1+1}{2}$ but the lower $\frac{1}{2}=\frac{1+0}{2}$ I would have thought.

Why with a change of variables does $ \int_0^1 x^z (1-x)^z dx$ become $\int_{-1}^1 \left(\frac{1+s}{2}\right)^z \left(\frac{1-s}{2}\right)^z \frac{1}{2}ds$?

Comment: Substitute $x=0,1$ in $s=2x-1$.

Comment: @Thomas Shelby yes that sorts that out thank you.

Comment: The endpoint $0$ in the $x$ variable corresponds to the endpoint $-1$ in the $s$ variable.